# React Native - ios Native Module not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-native-module, native-module

I'm following the example posted in the [official doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) for native module ios. I've set up everything, build it and run the application.

```
//  CAL.h    

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface CAL : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

```
// CAL.m

#import <React/RCTLog.h>
#import "CAL.h"

@implementation CAL

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(CAL);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(createCalendarEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
 RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}
@end
```

But when I check NativeModules from react-native it shows an empty object - {}.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Try checking `NativeModules.CAL` directly

Comment: Yes that's what I had to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like @chengsam mentioned, when I access CAL directly in the following manner it works.

`const { CAL } = NativeModules;`
or
`NativeModules.CAL`

CAL still held the native module while NativeModules directly displayed {}